# make infinite loop pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I need this part of script work infinitely(send messages), but it works only one time and then stops

````
f = open('text.txt')
t = 1
with app:
    while True:
        for line in f.readlines():
            try:
                app.send_message(chat_id=line[13:].rstrip(), text=txt)
                print(f"Успешно написал в чат по ссылке {line}")
                time.sleep(0.5)
            except:
                print(f"Что-то пошло не так... Возможно в чате {line} включен медленный режим")```
````

Comment: You need to reopen the file each time through the `while` loop, or seek back to the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop stops when it gets to the end of the file. When the `while` loop repeats, there's nothing for the `for` loop to read because you're already at the end of the file.

You can seek to the beginning each time.

```
f = open('text.txt')
t = 1
with app:
    while True:
        f.seek(0)
        for line in f.readlines():
            try:
                app.send_message(chat_id=line[13:].rstrip(), text=txt)
                print(f"Успешно написал в чат по ссылке {line}")
                time.sleep(0.5)
            except:
                print(f"Что-то пошло не так... Возможно в чате {line} включен медленный режим")
```

Or you could save the contents to a list and loop through that.

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
t = 1
with app:
    while True:
        for line in lines:
            try:
                app.send_message(chat_id=line[13:].rstrip(), text=txt)
                print(f"Успешно написал в чат по ссылке {line}")
                time.sleep(0.5)
            except:
                print(f"Что-то пошло не так... Возможно в чате {line} включен медленный режим")
```